# Количество идущих подряд одинаковых записей PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | abs1 | true |
| a | abs2 | true |
| a | abs3 | false |
| a | abs4 | true |
| b | abs1 | true |
| b | abs2 | false |
| b | abs3 | true |

Нужно из этой таблички получить следующую:

| one | count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |

То есть подсчитать максимальное количество подряд идущих одинаковых записей в первом столбце, которые в третьем имеют статус "true"

Comment: Укажите ТОЧНО сортировку, которая обеспечивает показанный порядок записей.

Comment: Ну тут получается ORDER BY one ASC, two ASC

Comment: Ну тогда обычный gaps and islands. Группировка по разности двух ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Знать бы вообще что это и как правильно писать) Что-то написал, но в итоге просто получил 1, 2, 3, 4 в новой колонке для 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Можно оформить через LAG() - изменение фиксируем просто сравнивая текущую и предыдущую строку в столбце `three`. Пример:

```
WITH tempTable (
  one,
  two,
  three
)
AS (
  SELECT 'a', 'abs1', true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'abs2', true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'abs3', false
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'abs4', true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'abs1', true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'abs2', false
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'abs3', true
)

SELECT
  s.one,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      LAG(three) OVER (PARTITION BY one) prevThree,
      one, 
      two,
      three
    FROM
      tempTable t
  ) s
WHERE
  s.prevThree = s.three
  OR s.prevThree IS NULL
GROUP BY
  s.one
```